# Massive datasets with the randomForest package

Tags: r, package

I have about 300,000 rows of data and 10 features in my model and I want to fit a random forest from the `randomForest` package in `R`.

To maximise the amount of trees I can get in the forest in a fixed window of time without ruining generalisation what are sensible ranges that I should set the parameters to?

Comment: This is more a statistical question than a programming question you should consider migrating this to crossvalidated and you might also want to explore cross-validation to set your parameters!

Comment: @dickoa This is a time complexity problem. I want to know the ranges of parameter values where time complexity is feasible. I will then use cross validation within the cartesian product of these intervals.

Comment: I don't see what's preventing you from simply doing some tests on a smaller version of your data to figure this out yourself.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Usually you can get away with just `mtry`as explained here and the default is often best:

https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/50210/caret-and-randomforest-number-of-trees

But there is a function `tuneRF` with randomForest that will help you find optimal `ntree` or `mtry` as explained here:

[setting values for ntree and mtry for random forest regression model](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13956435/setting-values-for-ntree-and-mtry-for-random-forest-regression-model)

The time it takes you will have to test yourself - it's going to be the products of folds*tuning*ntrees.

The only speculative point I would add is that with 300,000 rows of data you ***might*** reduce the runtime without loss of predictive accuracy by bootstrapping small samples of the data???