# How to determine the most suitable value for ntree while building random forests in r?

Tags: r, regression, random-forest

I'm doing a task which need to build random forests with regression. In the data set, there are 32 independent variables. How can i determine the value for number of trees I need to grow? Is there any command functions can help me to determine ntree value?

Comment: Possible duplicate of: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13956435/setting-values-for-ntree-and-mtry-for-random-forest-regression-model?rq=1

Comment: Useful link: https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/50210/caret-and-randomforest-number-of-trees .